# Sizing photo zooms in fancybox.js

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using fancybox on a site with many JPEGs. I use single large image files, at least double the final max viewing dimensions, heavily compressed to reduce KBs. The technique seems to work well and saves a lot of time of making x2 and x3 versions of each original and avoids using srcset.

There are alternative views of images which are viewed in a zoomed image via fancybox, but the zoomed images display at actual pixel size of the file, so I can't figure out how to control the final display size of fancybox'd zoomed images on screen.

Can it be done? Thanks, Peter H.

(the zoomed images are not all the same size)

Comment: You have to be more specific, what do you mean by "I can't figure out how to control the final display size"?

Comment: The images displayed by fancybox show at actual pixel size. I'd like, eg, for images to display at 50% of their actual pixel size.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fancyBox3, then you can use "afterLoad" callback to change image dimensions:

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
    afterLoad : function( instance, slide ) {
        if ( slide.type === 'image' ) {
            slide.width  = slide.width  * 0.5;
            slide.height = slide.height * 0.5;
        }
    }
});
```

If you wish to apply this to all future instances, then it is possible, too. Example:

```
$(document).on('onComplete.fb', function( e, instance, slide ) {
    // Your code goes here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful to know. I'm currently using v2.1.4 but will try a few pages with v3 plus the code above. Would adding the code just once in a page make the callback work for every instance of fancybox links on that page?

Comment: Only to selected items. I have updated the answer with example.